# Imported scss class names converted to hashes

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have a webpack configuration (based on React Universally). One thing I'm seeing is that class names on imported scss files are converted to hashes.

I tried as an alternative to import styles as an object and reference the style classes by name, but they simply disappear. Didn't see this behavior on other projects and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import './styles/scss/app.scss';

function App() {
    return (
      <Provider store={ store }>
          <IntlProvider>
              <MuiThemeProvider>
                  <Switch>
                      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                      <Route component={Error404} />
                  </Switch>
              </MuiThemeProvider>
          </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>
    )
}


import styles from './portfolio.scss';

[...]
return (
<div className={cx(styles.phoneAni, {active: imageOpen})}>
    <img src="img/iphone_s01_1.png"/>
    <img src="img/iphone_s01_0.png"/>
    <img src="img/iphone_s02_2.png"/>
</div>
);
```

webpack

```
export default function webpackConfigFactory(buildOptions) {
  const { target, optimize = false } = buildOptions;

  const isOptimize = optimize;
  const isDev = !isOptimize;
  const isClient = target === 'client';
  const isServer = target === 'server';
  const isNode = !isClient;

  // Preconfigure some ifElse helper instnaces. See the util docs for more
  // information on how this util works.
  const ifDev = ifElse(isDev);
  const ifOptimize = ifElse(isOptimize);
  const ifNode = ifElse(isNode);
  const ifClient = ifElse(isClient);
  const ifDevClient = ifElse(isDev && isClient);
  const ifOptimizeClient = ifElse(isOptimize && isClient);

  console.log(`==> Creating ${isOptimize ? 'an optimised' : 'a development'} bundle configuration for the "${target}"`);

  const bundleConfig = isServer || isClient
    // This is either our "server" or "client" bundle.
    ? config(['bundles', target])
    // Otherwise it must be an additional node bundle.
    : config(['additionalNodeBundles', target]);

  if (!bundleConfig) {
    throw new Error('No bundle configuration exists for target:', target);
  }

  const localIdentName = ifDev('[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]', '[hash:base64:10]');

  let webpackConfig = {
    // Define our entry chunks for our bundle.
    entry: {
      // We name our entry files "index" as it makes it easier for us to
      // import bundle output files (e.g. `import server from './build/server';`)
      index: removeNil([
        // Required to support hot reloading of our client.
        ifDevClient(() => `webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&path=http://${config('host')}:${config('clientDevServerPort')}/__webpack_hmr`),
        // We are using polyfill.io instead of the very heavy babel-polyfill.
        // Therefore we need to add the regenerator-runtime as polyfill.io
        // doesn't support this.
        ifClient('regenerator-runtime/runtime'),
        // The source entry file for the bundle.
        path.resolve(appRootDir.get(), bundleConfig.srcEntryFile),
      ]),
    },

    // Bundle output configuration.
    output: {
      // The dir in which our bundle should be output.
      path: path.resolve(appRootDir.get(), bundleConfig.outputPath),
      // The filename format for our bundle's entries.
      filename: ifOptimizeClient(
        // For our production client bundles we include a hash in the filename.
        // That way we won't hit any browser caching issues when our bundle
        // output changes.
        // Note: as we are using the WebpackMd5Hash plugin, the hashes will
        // only change when the file contents change. This means we can
        // set very aggressive caching strategies on our bundle output.
        '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
        // For any other bundle (typically a server/node) bundle we want a
        // determinable output name to allow for easier importing/execution
        // of the bundle by our scripts.
        '[name].js',
      ),
      // The name format for any additional chunks produced for the bundle.
      chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
      // When targetting node we will output our bundle as a commonjs2 module.
      libraryTarget: ifNode('commonjs2', 'var'),
      // This is the web path under which our webpack bundled client should
      // be considered as being served from.
      publicPath: ifDev(
        // As we run a seperate development server for our client and server
        // bundles we need to use an absolute http path for the public path.
        `http://${config('host')}:${config('clientDevServerPort')}${config('bundles.client.webPath')}`,
        // Otherwise we expect our bundled client to be served from this path.
        bundleConfig.webPath,
      ),
    },

    target: isClient
      // Only our client bundle will target the web as a runtime.
      ? 'web'
      // Any other bundle must be targetting node as a runtime.
      : 'node',

    // Ensure that webpack polyfills the following node features for use
    // within any bundles that are targetting node as a runtime. This will be
    // ignored otherwise.
    node: {
      __dirname: true,
      __filename: true,
    },

    // Source map settings.
    devtool: ifElse(
        // Include source maps for ANY node bundle so that we can support
        // nice stack traces for errors (the source maps get consumed by
        // the `node-source-map-support` module to allow for this).
        isNode
        // Always include source maps for any development build.
        || isDev
        // Allow for the following flag to force source maps even for production
        // builds.
        || config('includeSourceMapsForOptimisedClientBundle'),
      )(
      // Produces an external source map (lives next to bundle output files).
      'source-map',
      // Produces no source map.
      'hidden-source-map',
    ),

    // Performance budget feature.
    // This enables checking of the output bundle size, which will result in
    // warnings/errors if the bundle sizes are too large.
    // We only want this enabled for our production client.  Please
    // see the webpack docs on how you can configure this to your own needs:
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/performance/
    performance: ifOptimizeClient(
      // Enable webpack's performance hints for production client builds.
      { hints: 'warning' },
      // Else we have to set a value of "false" if we don't want the feature.
      false,
    ),

    resolve: {
      // These extensions are tried when resolving a file.
      extensions: config('bundleSrcTypes').map(ext => `.${ext}`),

      // This is required for the modernizr-loader
      // @see https://github.com/peerigon/modernizr-loader
      alias: mergeDeep(
        {
          modernizr$: path.resolve(appRootDir.get(), './.modernizrrc'),
        },
        // For our optimised builds we will alias to the optimised versions
        // of React and ReactDOM.
        ifOptimize({
          react$: path.resolve(
            appRootDir.get(), './node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js',
          ),
          'react-dom$': path.resolve(
            appRootDir.get(), './node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js',
          ),
          'react-dom/server$': path.resolve(
            appRootDir.get(), './node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom-server.min.js',
          ),
        }),
      ),
    },

    // We don't want our node_modules to be bundled with any bundle that is
    // targetting the node environment, prefering them to be resolved via
    // native node module system. Therefore we use the `webpack-node-externals`
    // library to help us generate an externals configuration that will
    // ignore all the node_modules.
    externals: removeNil([
      ifNode(
        () => nodeExternals(
          // Some of our node_modules may contain files that depend on our
          // webpack loaders, e.g. CSS or SASS.
          // For these cases please make sure that the file extensions are
          // registered within the following configuration setting.
          {
            whitelist:
              removeNil([
                // We always want the source-map-support included in
                // our node target bundles.
                'source-map-support/register',
                // We want react bundled with our node bundles for the optimised
                // builds as we are going to resolve to the optmised versions
                // of react via the webpack alias configuration.
                ifOptimize('react'),
                ifOptimize('react-dom'),
                ifOptimize('react-dom/server'),
              ])
              // And any items that have been whitelisted in the config need
              // to be included in the bundling process too.
              .concat(config('nodeExternalsFileTypeWhitelist') || []),
          },
        ),
      ),
    ]),

    plugins: removeNil([
      // This grants us source map support, which combined with our webpack
      // source maps will give us nice stack traces for our node executed
      // bundles.
      // We use the BannerPlugin to make sure all of our chunks will get the
      // source maps support installed.
      ifNode(() => new webpack.BannerPlugin({
        banner: 'require("source-map-support").install();',
        raw: true,
        entryOnly: false,
      })),

      // We use this so that our generated [chunkhash]'s are only different if
      // the content for our respective chunks have changed.  This optimises
      // our long term browser caching strategy for our client bundle, avoiding
      // cases where browsers end up having to download all the client chunks
      // even though 1 or 2 may have only changed.
      ifClient(() => new WebpackMd5Hash()),

      // These are special flags that you can use in your code in order to
      // have advanced control over what is included/excluded in your bundles.
      // For example you may only want certain parts of your code to be
      // included/ran under certain conditions.
      //
      // The DefinePlugin is used by webpack to substitute any code
      // that matches the property keys of the object you provide it below with
      // the given value that has been assigned to each respective property.
      //
      // For example you may have the following in your code:
      //   if (process.env.BUILD_FLAG_IS_CLIENT === true) {
      //     console.log('Foo');
      //   }
      //
      // If the BUILD_FLAG_IS_CLIENT was assigned a value of `false` the above
      // code would be converted to the following by the webpack bundling
      // process:
      //   if (false === true) {
      //     console.log('Foo');
      //   }
      //
      // When your bundle is built using the UglifyJsPlugin unreachable code
      // blocks like in the example above will be removed from the bundle
      // final output. This is helpful for extreme cases where you want to
      // ensure that code is only included/executed on specific targets, or for
      // doing debugging.
      //
      // NOTE: You may be used to having to do NODE_ENV = production here to
      // get optimized React/ReactDOM builds. Almost every blog and example
      // will tell you to do this.  I have decided against this model as it
      // often confused me when I was passing custom NODE_ENV values
      // such as "staging" / "test" to my scripts.  Therefore to avoid any
      // confusion we instead use the webpack alias feature to target the
      // pre-optimised dist versions of React/ReactDOM when required.
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        // Is this the "client" bundle?
        'process.env.BUILD_FLAG_IS_CLIENT': JSON.stringify(isClient),
        // Is this the "server" bundle?
        'process.env.BUILD_FLAG_IS_SERVER': JSON.stringify(isServer),
        // Is this a node bundle?
        'process.env.BUILD_FLAG_IS_NODE': JSON.stringify(isNode),
        // Is this a development build?
        'process.env.BUILD_FLAG_IS_DEV': JSON.stringify(isDev),
      }),

      // Generates a JSON file containing a map of all the output files for
      // our webpack bundle.  A necessisty for our server rendering process
      // as we need to interogate these files in order to know what JS/CSS
      // we need to inject into our HTML. We only need to know the assets for
      // our client bundle.
      ifClient(() =>
        new AssetsPlugin({
          filename: config('bundleAssetsFileName'),
          path: path.resolve(appRootDir.get(), bundleConfig.outputPath),
        }),
      ),

      // We don't want webpack errors to occur during development as it will
      // kill our dev servers.
      ifDev(() => new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()),

      // We need this plugin to enable hot reloading of our client.
      ifDevClient(() => new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()),

      // For our production client we need to make sure we pass the required
      // configuration to ensure that the output is minimized/optimized.
      ifOptimizeClient(
        () => new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
          minimize: true,
        }),
      ),

      // For our production client we need to make sure we pass the required
      // configuration to ensure that the output is minimized/optimized.
      ifOptimizeClient(
        () => new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          sourceMap: config('includeSourceMapsForOptimisedClientBundle'),
          compress: {
            screw_ie8: true,
            warnings: false,
          },
          mangle: {
            screw_ie8: true,
          },
          output: {
            comments: false,
            screw_ie8: true,
          },
        }),
      ),

      // For the production build of the client we need to extract the CSS into
      // CSS files.
      ifOptimizeClient(
        () => new ExtractTextPlugin({
          filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].css',
          allChunks: true,
        }),
      ),

      // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
      // START: HAPPY PACK PLUGINS
      //
      // @see https://github.com/amireh/happypack/
      //
      // HappyPack allows us to use threads to execute our loaders. This means
      // that we can get parallel execution of our loaders, significantly
      // improving build and recompile times.
      //
      // This may not be an issue for you whilst your project is small, but
      // the compile times can be signficant when the project scales. A lengthy
      // compile time can significantly impare your development experience.
      // Therefore we employ HappyPack to do threaded execution of our
      // "heavy-weight" loaders.

      // HappyPack 'javascript' instance.
      happyPackPlugin({
        name: 'happypack-javascript',
        // We will use babel to do all our JS processing.
        loaders: [{
          path: 'babel-loader',
          // We will create a babel config and pass it through the plugin
          // defined in the project configuration, allowing additional
          // items to be added.
          query: config('plugins.babelConfig')(
            // Our "standard" babel config.
            {
              // We need to ensure that we do this otherwise the babelrc will
              // get interpretted and for the current configuration this will mean
              // that it will kill our webpack treeshaking feature as the modules
              // transpilation has not been disabled within in.
              babelrc: false,

              presets: [
                // For our client bundles we transpile all the latest ratified
                // ES201X code into ES5, safe for browsers.  We exclude module
                // transilation as webpack takes care of this for us, doing
                // tree shaking in the process.
                ifClient(['latest', { es2015: { modules: false } }]),
                // For a node bundle we use the awesome babel-preset-env which
                // acts like babel-preset-latest in that it supports the latest
                // ratified ES201X syntax, however, it will only transpile what
                // is necessary for a target environment.  We have configured it
                // to target our current node version.  This is cool because
                // recent node versions have extensive support for ES201X syntax.
                // Also, we have disabled modules transpilation as webpack will
                // take care of that for us ensuring tree shaking takes place.
                // NOTE: Make sure you use the same node version for development
                // and production.
                ifNode(['env', { targets: { node: true }, modules: false }]),
                // Stage 3 javascript syntax.
                // "Candidate: complete spec and initial browser implementations."
                // Add anything lower than stage 3 at your own risk. :)
                'stage-0',
                // JSX
                'react',
              ].filter(x => x != null),

              plugins: [
                'transform-class-properties',
                'syntax-decorators',
                'transform-decorators-legacy',
                // This decorates our components with  __self prop to JSX elements,
                // which React will use to generate some runtime warnings.
                ifDev('transform-react-jsx-self'),
                // Adding this will give us the path to our components in the
                // react dev tools.
                ifDev('transform-react-jsx-source'),
                // Replaces the React.createElement function with one that is
                // more optimized for production.
                // NOTE: Symbol needs to be polyfilled. Ensure this feature
                // is enabled in the polyfill.io configuration.
                ifOptimize('transform-react-inline-elements'),
                // Hoists element creation to the top level for subtrees that
                // are fully static, which reduces call to React.createElement
                // and the resulting allocations. More importantly, it tells
                // React that the subtree hasn’t changed so React can completely
                // skip it when reconciling.
                ifOptimize('transform-react-constant-elements'),
              ].filter(x => x != null),
              env: {
                  production: {
                      presets: [
                        ifOptimize('react-optimize'),
                      ].filter(x => x != null)
                  }
              },
            },
            buildOptions,
          ),
        }],
      }),

      // HappyPack 'css' instance for development client.
      ifDevClient(
        () => happyPackPlugin({
          name: 'happypack-devclient-css',
          loaders: [
            'style-loader',
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              // Include sourcemaps for dev experience++.
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                modules: true,
                importLoaders: 1,
                localIdentName,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                outputStyle: 'expanded',
                sourceMap: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      ),

      // END: HAPPY PACK PLUGINS
      // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]),
    module: {
      rules: removeNil([
        // JAVASCRIPT
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          // We will defer all our js processing to the happypack plugin
          // named "happypack-javascript".
          // See the respective plugin within the plugins section for full
          // details on what loader is being implemented.
          loader: 'happypack/loader?id=happypack-javascript',
          include: removeNil([
            ...bundleConfig.srcPaths.map(srcPath =>
              path.resolve(appRootDir.get(), srcPath),
            ),
            ifOptimizeClient(path.resolve(appRootDir.get(), 'src/html')),
          ]),
        },

        // CSS
        // This is bound to our server/client bundles as we only expect to be
        // serving the client bundle as a Single Page Application through the
        // server.
        ifElse(isClient || isServer)(
          mergeDeep(
            {
              test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
            },
            // For development clients we will defer all our css processing to the
            // happypack plugin named "happypack-devclient-css".
            // See the respective plugin within the plugins section for full
            // details on what loader is being implemented.
            ifDevClient({
              loaders: [
                  'happypack/loader?id=happypack-devclient-css',
                  {
                      loader: 'css-loader',
                      // Include sourcemaps for dev experience++.
                      options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                        modules: true,
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        localIdentName,
                      },
                  },
                  {
                      loader: 'sass-loader',
                      options: {
                        outputStyle: 'expanded',
                        sourceMap: true,
                      },
                  },
              ],
            }),
            // For a production client build we use the ExtractTextPlugin which
            // will extract our CSS into CSS files. We don't use happypack here
            // as there are some edge cases where it fails when used within
            // an ExtractTextPlugin instance.
            // Note: The ExtractTextPlugin needs to be registered within the
            // plugins section too.
            ifOptimizeClient(() => ({
              loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        // Include sourcemaps for dev experience++.
                        options: {
                          sourceMap: true,
                          modules: true,
                          importLoaders: 1,
                          localIdentName,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                          sourceMap: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
              }),
            })),
            // When targetting the server we use the "/locals" version of the
            // css loader, as we don't need any css files for the server.
            ifNode({
              loaders: [
                  `css-loader/locals?modules=1&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=${localIdentName}`,
                  'sass-loader',
              ],
          }),
          ),
        ),

        // ASSETS (Images/Fonts/etc)
        // This is bound to our server/client bundles as we only expect to be
        // serving the client bundle as a Single Page Application through the
        // server.
        ifElse(isClient || isServer)(() => ({
          test: new RegExp(`\\.(${config('bundleAssetTypes').join('|')})$`, 'i'),
          loader: 'file-loader',
          query: {
            // What is the web path that the client bundle will be served from?
            // The same value has to be used for both the client and the
            // server bundles in order to ensure that SSR paths match the
            // paths used on the client.
            publicPath: isDev
              // When running in dev mode the client bundle runs on a
              // seperate port so we need to put an absolute path here.
              ? `http://${config('host')}:${config('clientDevServerPort')}${config('bundles.client.webPath')}`
              // Otherwise we just use the configured web path for the client.
              : config('bundles.client.webPath'),
            // We only emit files when building a web bundle, for the server
            // bundle we only care about the file loader being able to create
            // the correct asset URLs.
            emitFile: isClient,
          },
        })),

        // MODERNIZR
        // This allows you to do feature detection.
        // @see https://modernizr.com/docs
        // @see https://github.com/peerigon/modernizr-loader
        ifClient({
          test: /\.modernizrrc.js$/,
          loader: 'modernizr-loader',
        }),
        ifClient({
          test: /\.modernizrrc(\.json)?$/,
          loader: 'modernizr-loader!json-loader',
        }),
      ]),
    },
  };

  if (isOptimize && isClient) {
    webpackConfig = withServiceWorker(webpackConfig, bundleConfig);
  }

  // Apply the configuration middleware.
  return config('plugins.webpackConfig')(webpackConfig, buildOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class names are converted to hashes because you're using [css modules.](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) In order to disable that you must set `modules: false,` in your css-loader options object. Or you may still use css modules, but you need to translate the classes in your html to use generated ones.

Comment: Another way to deal with this, I found is surrounding the css you don't want converted with `:global { /* unconverted css */ }`

Comment: Right, if you still want to use css modules. There is no point in wrapping your whole css in `:global{}`

Answer (score 3):

how about localIdentName?
default is _[hash:base64:22]

webpack.config.js

```
test: /\.(css|sass)$/,
use: [{
  loader: "css-loader?modules",
  options: {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[local]'
    //sample(if u use custom className)
    //localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
    //localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:5]'   
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use

```
{
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
           modules: {
                localIdentName: '[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
           }
      }
},
```

More info https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#object